# Typeahead js no found - laravel 5.3

Tags: php, controller, laravel-5.3, typeahead.js

I'm looking for a way to include typeahead.js, but I can not get it to work.

Also, I am doing tests with a single field, but I would like to do it with at least 5, i use LARAVEL 5.3

---

### Controller

```
public function search(){
$nomenclaturas = DB::table('nomenclaturas')->get(array('nome'));
return view('buscar.index')->with('nomenclaturas', $nomenclaturas);
}

public function searchByNomenclatura($nomenclatura){
$nomenclaturas   = Nomenclatura::where('nome', 'LIKE', "$nomenclatura%")->get(array('nome'));
return response()->json($nomenclaturas);
```

}

---

### Routes

```
Route::get('buscar','BuscarController@search');
Route::get('/searchbynomenclatura/{nomenclatura}', 'BuscarController@searchByNomenclatura');
```

---

### View

```
<input type="text" class="typeahead">

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var nomenclaturas = new Bloodhound({
        datumTokenizer: function(datum) {
            return Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace(datum.value);
        },
        queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
        prefetch: { 
            url: "/",
            transform: function(response) {
                    return $.map(response, function(nomenclatura) {
                        return { value: nomenclatura.nome };
                    });
                }
        },
        remote: {
            wildcard: '%QUERY',
            url: "searchbynomenclatura/%QUERY",
                transform: function(response) {
                    return $.map(response, function(nomenclatura) {
                        return { value: nomenclatura.nome };
                    });
                }
        }
    });

    $('.typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: false,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 2,
        limit: 10
    },
    {
        name: 'Nomenclaturas',
        display: 'value',
        source: nomenclaturas,
        templates: {
                header: '<h4 class="dropdown">Nomenclaturas</h4>'
        }   
    }
});

</script>
```

---

### Model

```
protected $table = 'nomenclaturas';

protected $fillable = ['nome','capi','part','subp','frac','coma','rimp','rexp','anex','cimp','cexp','ogen','oimp','oexp'
];
```

Comment: Please, be more specific: Why does not work? Can you add the exact error you are receiving?

Comment: Do not display the results of the search in the input <input type="text" class="typeahead">